# The Density Matrix $\rho$ and the Von Neumann Entropy

Tags: linear-algebra, probability, complex-numbers, information-theory, quantum-mechanics

We know that the Von Neumann entropy can be given by the following formula (up to constants):

$S=-\text{Tr}(\rho \log(\rho))$

Where $\rho$ is the density matrix.

Now for situations such as Electromagnetically Induced Transparency then time evolution and superpositions are involved, we get that $\rho=\rho^\dagger\in\mathbb{C}$. With this in mind, my question is this:

Does this imply that in some cases we get that $S\leq0$?

Comment: As $\rho(=\rho^\dagger)\geq 0$ and $\operatorname{tr}\rho=1$ all the eigenvalues $\lambda_j$ of $\rho$ lie in $[0,1]$. This implies $S=-\sum_j\lambda_k\ln\lambda_j\geq 0$ with $S=0$ if and only if $\rho$ is a pure state.

Comment: So when taking the matrix product between $\rho$ and $\log(\rho)$, the diagonal is strictly real and non positive?

Comment: As $\rho$ is hermitian it is unitarily diagonalizable, e.g. there exists unitary $U$ such that $\rho=U^\dagger\operatorname{diag}(\lambda_1,\ldots,\lambda_n)U$ with $\lambda_1,\ldots,\lambda_n\in (0,1)$, $\sum_j\lambda_j=1$ and thus $\rho\cdot\log\rho=U^\dagger\operatorname{diag}(\lambda_1\log\lambda_1,\ldots,\lambda_n\log\lambda_n)U$ as is readily verified. Now $\lambda_j\in [0,1]$ implies $\lambda_j\log\lambda_j\leq 0$ so thanks to the minus sign in $S$ we get $S\geq 0$ or arbitrary $\rho\in\mathbb D(\mathcal H)$.

Comment: @FrederikvomEnde In your comment you made the statement: if $\rho=U^\dagger\operatorname{diag}(\lambda_1,\ldots,\lambda_n)U$ then $\rho\cdot\log\rho=U^\dagger\operatorname{diag}(\lambda_1\log\lambda_1,\ldots,\lambda_n\log\lambda_n)U$ for a $U$ unitary. How do you prove this statement?

Comment: Note that $\rho^n=U^\dagger\operatorname{diag}(\lambda_1^n,\ldots,\lambda_n^n)U$ for all $n\in\mathbb N_0$ because $UU^\dagger=I$ so inserting the matrix into the series expansion of the logarithm means applying log to the diagonal. More generally, this is a direct application of continuous functional calculus (i.e. how to extend a continuous map to matrices or bounded operators), as for example loosely explained [in one of my earlier answers](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3197928/diagonal-representation-of-positive-power-of-a-compact-positive-operator/3202929#3202929).